# Как нарисовать букву Z?

Tags: c++, символы

Задание нарисовать букву Z. Нужно напечатать на экран.

Я пока написала только верхнюю палку
А дальше не знаю как печатать наискосок, только начала учить С++. Кто знает, как сделать? Какой конструкцией мне воспользоваться, чтобы
это реализовать?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "*";
}
```

Comment: 8 пробелов + * + endl (перевод строки), потом 7 пробелов + * + endl и т.д. и в конце опять палку :)

Comment: Только спросила уже минус ((( Может есть функция чтоб печатать наискосок?

Comment: @Алиса Не переживайте, минус политический. Функцию такую нужно писать самому.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу"

Comment: @Mikhailo Чтобы подтвердить мое предположение, стоило скопировать ваш комментарий под ответом снизу полностью.

Comment: @Mikhailo Автор пытался решить задачу самостоятельно, указал что именно вызвало трудности ("как печатать наискосок") и привел код. Все условия соблюдены.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Проводим верхний отрезок
{
    std::cout << "*";

}
cout <<" "<< endl;
for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--) // Здесь спускаемся по строкам
{

    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) // Здесь перемещаемся, на конец верхней строки, и движемся по диагонали на начало нижней строки.
    {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "*" << endl; // Ставим наш символ

}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Проводим нижний отрезок
{
    std::cout << "*";

}
```

Comment: Хоть бы объяснился, хейтер)

Comment: А есть люди в себе, которые объяснят минуса?)

Comment: Минуса не мои, но решение не спортивное, не интересное чтоль :) но картину ваших балов скрасил как мог :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков с этим соглашусь, но тот кто задал вопрос в школу ходит, по этому максимально понятно и просто, да я не отказываюсь, что написал не очень. Но можно было сказать, я бы объяснил почему так сделал. А молча репутацию портить, мне кажется, что мой код лучше такого поведения, ахаха

Comment: В этом и суть, такие вопросы разжеваны в учебнике и перед тем как идти на форум с вопросами - нужно почитать книжки, ваш ответ не несет пользы сообществу, только автору, в отличие от неординарного подхода к решению:) при этом если извратиться и сделать рекурсию - шансы получить плюсы - больше :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков виноват(, но просто хотелось помочь...

Comment: Да ни в чем вы не виноваты, есть желание - помогайте :) просто не расчитывайте на плюсы  от решения школьных задач :)

Comment: @Вадим Наискосок не в ту сторону! И в диагонали должно быть не 10 символов а 8! :) Видимо за это минус!

Comment: @Mikhailo, что плохого, что я хочу помочь человеку, можно просто указать мне, что я сделал не так и всё. А не приплетать политику. Да и вам советую, а то так в школах как кое-где, начнут преподавать фашизм, с 1-го класса, но не об этом.

Comment: @Mikhailo, вы не сидели рядом и не знаете, пыталась она или нет. Я посчитал, что да. Вы могли просто проигнорировать этот вопрос и всё, если вы испытываете к этому прямую неприязнь, то это уже другое.

Comment: Данный ответ плохой: непонятный блок кода, непонятно что делающий и непонятно чем отличающийся от кода в вопросе. Как минимум нужно добавить пояснения как это работает.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, исправил

Comment: И для блока "проводим диагональ" нужны подробные пояснения - ведь вопрос был именно в том - как это сделать. Сейчас получается - какая-то магия

Answer (score -1):

Скучно стало xD на здоровье школьникам :)

```
int DrawZ(int i){
    if(i>0){
        cout << (i%10==0?"\n":(i>90?"*":(i<10?"*":(10-i%10==i/10?"*":" "))));
        i = DrawZ(--i);
    }
    return i;
}

int DrawV(int i){
    if(i>0){
        cout << (i%10==0?"\n":(((i-5)%10==(i-5)/20)|| 9-(i+4)%10==(i+4)/20 ?"*":" "));
        i = DrawV(--i);
    }
    
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    DrawV(89);
    DrawZ(100);
    return 0;
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Tbqsbo134