# x ? y : z - Что это за выражение в C++?

Tags: c++

Попытался сам найти, но даже названия не знаю этого выражения. Что оно делает и как называется?

Так примерно это используют:

*переменная* = *число* ? *другое число* : *переменная*

Comment: Тернарный оператор: `x ? y : z => if(x) { return y} else { return z}` Вот по теме, интересное :) https://habr.com/ru/post/205848/

Comment: Спасибо, но теперь у меня другой вопрос: Тернарный оператор быстрее if и else ?? Или их скорость одинакова? @ВладимирКлыков

Comment: Одинакова, в ассемблерном коде это будет `if then else` выражение, это просто способ записи для случаев `a = x?y:z`, когда запись ведется одновременно с присвоением(хотя этим и не ограничивается), посмотрите по ссылке на хабр, там интересные примеры использования. вот пример недавнего извращения с тернарным оператором(там где if else - заняло бы пару строк https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1402812/Как-нарисовать-букву-z/1402848#1402848)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Answer (score -1):

Это тернарный оператор который можно интерпретировать вот так:

```
if(x){
    return y;
}
else{
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Простите но на ответ это не тянет :) хоть бы описали подводные камни(то же самое висит комментарием задолго до вашего ответа :)

Comment: согласен, хотя бы добавить, что тернарка возвращает значение в отличие от if-else statement